# What are ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED files and folders for?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

I've moved my home folder from an old to a new computer using [this HowTo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124174/how-do-i-move-my-encrypted-home-to-a-new-computer).
The old machine was running Xubuntu 11.10 the new is running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

On both machines the users where created with encrypted home folder turned on.

Besides other oddities I have now **31 folders and 25 files** in my home directory which start with

> **ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED. ...**

- Why are these files there?
- What are they for?
- How can I get rid, switch off, hide them .... basically get back to where it was before?

Comment: I ended up re-installing and moving the files via a external HDD. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The files are files from your old encrypted home directory. If you mount the directory containing those encrypted files without encryption enabled or with a different key/passphrase they will fail decryption and show up as `ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED...`. To fix that you have to mount the directory with the proper key/passphrase that was originally used to encrypt them.