# Moving Encrypted Folders

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, ssd, passwd

How can i move Encrypted folder(everything) to new Disk, my HDD that has Linux is about to blow, its so slow. 
So I bought SSD but, how can i move encrypted folders because my Linux folders are encrypted.
I have tried Searching Info but no luck, I have tried everything I know.
I'm trying to move the whole Linux to different Partition.

Answer (score 0):

You used the word folder, which makes you might be talking about an encrypted /home folder. If that's the case, here's a really good answer.

[How do I move my encrypted /home to a new computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124174/how-do-i-move-my-encrypted-home-to-a-new-computer)

If you're talking about moving an entire LVM, maybe this discussion will help.

[How to migrate an encrypted LVM install to a new disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260777/how-to-migrate-an-encrypted-lvm-install-to-a-new-disk)

Good luck.